# Why observer->getEvent() gives the option to bring orders ids?

Tags: orders, magento2.2.6

I don't understand why Magento gives the option to bring orders id's instead of just the recently order id, I'm developing a module and using this on the **checkout_onepage_controller_success_action** event:

```
    $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    $orderShippingMethod = $order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();

    $mediaBaseUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);;

    foreach($orderIds as $orderId)
    {
        $order = $this->_order->load($orderId);
        /// more code...
    }
```

Is there a situation when this code will return me more than one id?

Comment: you can use it like this to get the last order id $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0] . But seems its a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Its not returning more than one order Id or array of order Ids. If you go through the implementation where this event is dispatched. your confusion will be clear. If you see this file

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * Order success action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
        if (!$this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator::class)->isValid()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }
        $session->clearQuote();
        //@todo: Refactor it to match CQRS
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
            ['order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()]]
        );
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Here you can see that Event object which is returned under 'order_ids' variable. Hence as the getter method is `$observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();`

Further if you see from how `$session->getLastOrderId()`
works. You may refer the following class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Checkout\Model\Type;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory as CustomerDataFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveClassComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Onepage
{
   // other methods or functions
   /**
     * Get last order increment id by order id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastOrderId()
    {
        $lastId = $this->getCheckout()->getLastOrderId();
        $orderId = false;
        if ($lastId) {
            $order = $this->_orderFactory->create();
            $order->load($lastId);
            $orderId = $order->getIncrementId();
        }
        return $orderId;
    }
}
```